# Detecting Key Press/ Key Down iOS

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard-events

I am developing a library, which will be used in an app,
where I need to know the timestamp of key pressed (key down and key up moments), in the iOS(iPhone) virtual keyboard.

I was trying to do it by inheritance from `UIViewController` and override `pressesBegan` and `pressesEnded` functions like [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-detect-keyboard-input-using-pressesbegan-and-pressesended), but it turns out its only working for **external physical keyboards** (so like >1% users of iPhones?)

I was trying to do this by getting all the textFields:

```
func getAllTextFields(fromView view: UIView)-> [UITextField] {
    return view.subviews.flatMap { (view) -> [UITextField] in
        if view is UITextField {
            return [(view as! UITextField)]
        } else {
            return getAllTextFields(fromView: view)
        }
    }.flatMap({$0})
}
```

and use of `.addTarget` method but there's no function which provide information about "key down" moment:

```
textFields.forEach{($0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldEditingBegin),
                                         for: .editingDidBegin))}

textFields.forEach{($0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange),
                                         for: .editingChanged))}

textFields.forEach{($0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidEnd),
                                         for: .editingDidEnd))}
```

The `.editingChanged` method can only be translated to "key up".
The other ones, tells us about whole textField, so the moment when user "tap" on it and not the moment when he "tap" the letter in the virtual keyboard.

I have not found anything useful for me in the `NotificationCenter`, `UIResponder` or `UITextFieldDelegate`.

So im asking if anyone knows how can I retrieve such information from a iOS keyboard,
im not very familiar with Extension mechanism and maybe there is some other stuff im able to do in my scenario.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect user's tap using UITextFieldDelegate

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) // became first responder
```

Comment: As I wrote in my question, the function You propose work the same way like `editingDidBegin` is working. So it will notify only when textField is tapped (touched). Not when individual key on the virtual keyboard is pressed.